# how to use the output value in php

Tags: php

I've got, a html file where clients can buy objects. There is an output line in order to calculate the sum of all the objects the user buy :

```
<output name="sum" for="i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24" id=sum></output>
```

Is there a way, then, in my php function, to get the output ? something like this :

```
$somme=($_GET['sum']);
```

in order to do :

```
$msg .= "Total = $sum";
```

Thank you;

Comment: clone `<output>` value into hidden input field then value can post on server or you can also calculate `for="i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24"` input value on server side

Comment: you mean like this :  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive your form values with GET/POST methods as:

**GET**

```
<?php
  if( $_GET['sum'] )
  {
     echo  "Total =".$_GET['sum'];
     exit();
  }
?>

<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
 <output name="sum" for="i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24" id=sum></output>
</form>
```

---

**POST**

```
<?php
  if( $_POST['sum'] )
  {
     echo  "Total =".$_POST['sum'];
     exit();
  }
?>

<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POSR">
 <output name="sum" for="i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24" id=sum></output>
</form>
```

Comment: So if I want to tell the php to send it via email. I put <?php
  if( $_GET['sum'] )
  {
     echo  "Total =".$_GET['sum'];
     exit();
  }
?>$a="me";
$c="@gmail.com";
$ad="$a$c";
$to = "$ad" ;
$subject = 'Une nouvelle commande de ' .$_GET['sum'];;